# Why does MessageQueue.Send(Object) NOT work when sending to remote private queue using FormatName?

Tags: c#, msmq, system.messaging

So...this one's got me baffled.

The target queue lives on *ServerA* where MSMQ is running in Workgroup mode.  The queue is a non-transactional, private queue, with Full rights on pretty much the world (including *NETWORK SERVICE*, but **EXCLUDING** *ANONYMOUS LOGON*).

I'm specifying the queue address as such: *FormatName:DIRECT=OS:ServerA\private$\targetqueue*.

If I'm interested in sending "fire-and-forget"-style (no need for transaction as there is no other persistence going on), I would assume it would be fine to simply call:

```
Message message = ConstructMessageWithObjectPayload(serializableObject);
using (MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queueAddress))
{
    queue.Send(message);
}
```

But strangely, the message never arrives in the target queue and enabling negative source journaling (which interestingly enough causes the message to be sent to the Dead-letter messages queue on the target server) tells me that it is a "Nontransactional message".

Consequently, using

```
queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

works!  Having a hard time wrapping my head around this.  What am I missing?

Also, I've seen a good number of posts by others where their similar problem was solved by giving *ANONYMOUS LOGIN* Full rights.  In what scenario is this necessary?  Giving *NETWORK SERVICE* access somewhat made sense because that is the account that MSMQ itself runs under.  If running in Workgroup mode like I am, is it necessary at all to assign rights to *Everyone* or even the account that my process runs under?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: This is very strange behavior - adding a transaction scope to the message should only be used if the queue is transactional. Are you sure the queue is non-transactional?